# Empty output when querying a specific field

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to get data from my elasticSearch index.

So I have the following index:

With Node, If I do a:

```
const hits = await elasticClient.search({
    index: esIndex,
    size: 999,
    sort: 'ts:desc',
    body: {
      query: {
        bool: {
          must: [
            {
              term: {
                userId: '56',
              },
            }
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

it will returns:

```
[
    {
        "_index": "events_rc",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "tf-szm0B_tB6kax4xmnr",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
            "userId": "56",
            "eventName": "synchronizationStart",
            "ts": 1571130486383
        }
    },
    {
        "_index": "events_rc",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "tP-szm0B_tB6kax4xmnr",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
            "userId": "56",
            "eventName": "showSynchronizationModal",
            "ts": 1571130447209
        }
    }
]
```

but If I do the following query:

```
const hits = await elasticClient.search({
    index: esIndex,
    size: 999,
    sort: 'ts:desc',
    body: {
      query: {
        bool: {
          must: [
            {
              term: {
                eventName: 'synchronizationStart',
              },
            }
          ],
        },
      },
    },
});
```

it will returns an empty array...

I would like to know why it can found matches with the `userId` but not with `eventName` ?

The mapping seems to be identicals for the 2 fields

```
"eventName": {
  "type": "text",
  "fields": {
  "keyword": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "ignore_above": 256
  }
}
```

```
"userId": {
  "type": "text",
  "fields": {
  "keyword": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "ignore_above": 256
  }
}
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**eventName** is of type  **text**. you should use match and not term.

> Avoid using the term query for text fields.

Taken from [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current//query-dsl-term-query.html)

If you will use **eventName.keyword** then you will have to add a custom normalizer to your field, otherwise you will have to search the **exact** term.

Change

```
    const hits = await elasticClient.search({
    index: esIndex,
    size: 999,
    sort: 'ts:desc',
    body: {
      query: {
        bool: {
          must: [
            {
              term: {
                eventName: 'synchronizationStart',
              },
            }
          ],
        },
      },
    },
});
```

To:

```
const hits = await elasticClient.search({
index: esIndex,
size: 999,
sort: 'ts:desc',
body: {
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: [
        {
          match: {
            eventName: 'synchronizationStart',
          },
        }
      ],
    },
  },
},
```

});

Comment: Why can I use term on userId but not with eventName ? both seems to be identical in the mapping

Comment: You can use the term query to find documents based on a precise value such as a price/number https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current//query-dsl-term-query.html#term-query-ex-request

Answer (score 1):

You need to query on the `eventName.keyword` field and it will work:

```
const hits = await elasticClient.search({
    index: esIndex,
    size: 999,
    sort: 'ts:desc',
    body: {
      query: {
        bool: {
          must: [
            {
              term: {
                'eventName.keyword': 'synchronizationStart',
              },
            }
          ],
        },
      },
    },
});
```